# CR-10 Ignoring Z-Stop Switch, Keeps Trying to Lower

Tags: marlin, creality-cr-10, ezabl

I have a CR-10 with TH3D's most recent firmware on it and an EZABL (Plug & Print Auto Bed Leveling Kit) installed.  My problem is that when I select "Auto Home", the printer ignores the Z-stop switch and keeps trying to lower the extruder, grinding and shuddering until I have to power it off.  I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Jack and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please explain what you mean by "Z-stop" is that the original switch or the inductive sensor? Also post which changes you made to the firmware to enable the EZABL sensor. As the question is posted now, there is not much information to work with for others to give you an answer.

Comment: Did it work before you installed EZABL?  If this is a mechanical Z-stop, have you verified separately that the switch (and the connector on the driver board) is making electrical contact when closed?

Comment: You may want to upgrade to TH3D's latest firmware (2.16a released on 10/2/2019). There's a fix in there that might relate to your issue if my rewire answer below doesn't work for you.
https://www.th3dstudio.com/knowledgebase/th3d-unified-firmware-package/

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue with my CR-10s. My black and white wires were reversed where I plugged them in to the motherboard in place of the stock z stop wires. I had to take apart the connector and swap them, as they came backwards from the mfg. Once I did that it worked perfectly.

The image I'm attaching helped me solve my issue. It is not mine, after much searching I found kenneycp's reply on this comment thread 
https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2975949/comments

[image: CR-10s wiring for BLTouch]